# Java HTTP response contains header only

Tags: java, http, sockets, tcp

I'm sending a HTTP request over a TCP socket and I'm getting the headers as response, though the content only contains a question mark. What is that about?

Here is my code:

```
Socket sock = null;
OutputStream out = null;
InputStream in = null;

try {
    // open socket
    sock = new Socket(this.addr, this.port);

    // get output stream
    out = sock.getOutputStream();

    // create request
    StringBuffer request = new StringBuffer();
    request.append("GET " + this.uri + " HTTP/1.1").append(this.CRLF);
    request.append("Host: " + this.host).append(this.CRLF);
    request.append("Cache-Control: no-cache").append(this.CRLF);
    request.append("Connection: keep-alive").append(this.CRLF);
    request.append("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11").append(this.CRLF);
    request.append("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8").append(this.CRLF);
    request.append("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch").append(this.CRLF);
    request.append("Accept-Language: en-GB").append(this.CRLF);
    request.append("Accept-Language: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3").append(this.CRLF);
    request.append("Pragma: no-cache").append(this.CRLF);
    request.append(this.CRLF);

    // write request per byte for the lulz
    for(int i = 0; i < request.length(); i++) {
        out.write(request.toString().getBytes()[i]);
        System.out.print((char) request.toString().getBytes()[i]);
    }

    out.flush();

    // open inputstream
    in = sock.getInputStream();

    int inbyte;

    // read response per byte for the lulz
    while((inbyte = in.read()) > 0) {
        System.out.print((char) inbyte);
    }

    // close out, in and socket
    out.close();
    in.close();
    sock.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can see my request headers, though here's the actual output:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.timseverien.nl
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB
Accept-Language: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Pragma: no-cache
```

And finally, the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 07:47:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2
X-Pingback: http://www.timseverien.nl/xmlrpc.php
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 2758
Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

?
```

**Why am I getting this question mark instead of the source code?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you formatting/parsing HTTP protocol manually? There are dozens of libraries that do that for you.

Comment: `Content-Encoding: gzip` - your response is compressed.

Comment: It says that the response's content is encoded as `gzip`, maybe it's printing it out but your terminal just prints out "?"

Comment: @Banthar make that an answer and I can accept it ;)

Comment: @Max Simply out of curiosity. Using libraries doesn't teach you how things work. I prefer spending hours in studying things I don't know about than spending a couple of minutes using libraries that wont teach me anything at all. I'm obsessed with learning. When I look at my old webdevelopment classmates, they haven't learn anything since they graduated. Unlike me.

Comment: It's a good practice to `close()` resources in a `finally` block.

Comment: @armandino wouldn't that force you to add a try-catch in the `finally` block to handle the `IOException` of the `close()` methods? A bit disappointing in my opinion, but if it's still a better practice to do so I will even though it might skip the other `close()` methods if one throws an `Exception`...

Comment: @TimS. It is more verbose, but if not done then `close()` won't get called if an exception is thrown. I usually use `IOUtils.closeQuietly(..)` from Apache commons. Or you can easily write your own utility method if you don't want to import a library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Content-Encoding: gzip` - your response is compressed and cannot be reliably printed to the screen.

Remove `Accept-Encoding` from your headers and you should receive plain text.

If you want to play with http, start with http/1.0. It's much easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

The content is gzipped, as Banthar pointed out already, but also the content-length is 2758 bytes but you've only read 1.

javadocs for InputStream.read() say:

> If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; 
>   otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte 
>   is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the 
>   value -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b.

I think your test for > 0 is wrong.

```
while((inbyte = in.read()) > 0) {
```

Should be:

```
while((inbyte = in.read()) >= 0) {
```

`in.read()` may return values in the range 0-255 inclusive (the full range of a byte). When no more data is available `in.read()` will return -1. This is why `in.read()` returns an `int` and not a `byte`.

Comment: Well, everything works fine after I have removed my `Accept-Encoding` header so reading the response byte-per-byte works well. Thanks for pointing out that my while loop condition is wrong. I think that's a typo because I did read the documentation.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that read loop except its possible inefficiency.

Comment: @EJP yes there is. There are 2758 bytes to read, but he only printed 1 because the first byte in the gzipped response was a zero. To confirm I just copied his code and pointed it at this question - when I tested it returned 11857 bytes but only printed a single question mark. Changing the loop to:

    while((inbyte = in.read(0) >= 0) {

... results in printing the whole body (the gzip encoded body that is, so still unreadable).